# Test hypothesis of the probabilities being the same using using Wald test statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, wald-test

I am trying to understand how to use the Wald test to test the hypothesis that the probabilities of getting a faulty product are the same in two samples.
The whole text of a task is:

> Two factories are manufacturing the same product. In a sample of 200
>   products from the first factory, 32 were faulty. In a sample of 230
>   products from the second factory, 21 were faulty. Using Wald test
>   statistic on α = 0.05, test hypothesis that the probabilities of
>   getting a faulty product are the same in both factories.

And here is what I have tried:

```
p0 <- 0
alpha <- 0.05
n1 <- 200
n2 <- 230
p1.est <- 32/200
p2.est <- 21/230

s1.est <- sqrt(n1 * p1.est * (1-p1.est))
s2.est <- sqrt(n2 * p2.est * (1-p2.est))

s.est <- sqrt(((n2-1) * s2.est^2 + (n1-1) * s1.est^2 )/(n2+n1-2))

tW.obs1 <- (p1.est - p2.est - p0)/s.est * sqrt(n1*n2/(n1 + n2))

t.CR.u <- qt(alpha/2, df = n1 + n2 - 2, lower.tail =F)
t.CR.l <- qt(alpha/2, df = n1 + n2 - 2, lower.tail =T)

CI.tW.l <- p1.est - p2.est + t.CR.l * (s.est/sqrt(n1*n2/(n1 + n2)))
CI.tW.u <- p1.est - p2.est + t.CR.u * (s.est/sqrt(n1*n2/(n1 + n2)))

p.val <- 2 * min(pt(tW.obs, df = 200 - 2), 1 - pt(tW.obs, df = 230 - 2))
```

So can you, please explain how to use the Wald test in terms of comparing the probabilities of binomial samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems in your approach.  For one, it seems you are using techniques typically seen in t-tests (pooled estimates of variance, using `pt`, etc).

Here is the solution to the problem.  Our hypothesis is that the fault probability in the two factories is the same.  Written mathematically

$$ H0: \pi_1-\pi_2=0$$

$$HA: \pi_1 - \pi_2 \neq 0 $$

To conduct the Wald test for the difference in proportions, we need to compute

$$ \dfrac{\hat{p_1} - \hat{p_2}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p_1}(1-\hat{p_1})}{n_1} + \dfrac{\hat{p_1}(1-\hat{p_2})}{n_2}}} $$

and compare this to a standard normal distribution.  In R...

```r
x1 = 32
n1 = 200
p1 = x1/n1

x2 = 21
n2 = 230
p2 = x2/n2

v = p1*(1-p1)/n1 + p2*(1-p2)/n2


z = (p1-p2)/sqrt(v)

p.val = 2*pnorm(z, lower.tail = F)
p.val
```

Which is approximately 0.032

Comment: Isn't the variance of the maximum-likelihood estimate of the parameter of interest usually calculated *at* the MLE in the construction of a Wald test statistic? Note that the test you've described coincides with Rao's score test (when you calculate the variance of the score at the null) & would often at least be billed as such (it's Pearson's chi-squared test if two-tailed).

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica  I think you're right.  This is the score statistic and not the Wald statistic.  Let me rectify that.

Comment: Well, I don't know whether it's generally regarded as a defining feature of a Wald test that the variance of the MLE is calculated at  the MLE - so perhaps you weren't wrong -, but calculating it anywhere else is unusual enough to deserve mention. The score in this case is directly proportional to the MLE, so it's only the question of where to estimate variance that might distinguish Rao's score test from the Wald test, if indeed anything does.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica No, you were right.  The previously posted solution was the Score test.  IMO, it makes more sense to estimate the variance under the null precisely because the statistic would then be comparable to the chi square test, as you noted.  In any case, either approach should be sufficient, but the one I've posted in the edit answers OP more directly.